# Convert json object to jquery array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working with Laravel 4, and I am new in JSON.
How to convert this value:

```
[{"connections":8},{"connections":5},{"connections":18}]
```

JSON from L4
To this value:

```
[8,5,18]
```

jQuery Array

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value you're showing is an array, not JSON. Sure that's correct?

Comment: Ah ok, That's correct.

Comment: @lesssugar I would say if that content was written to a file it would be perfectly valid json

Answer (score 0):

With the code snippet of your requirement, what I get is that you are looking forward to extract specific properties from an array of objects and populate in another array. You can simply iterate over the array to get the desired result.

```
var connectionsArray = [{"connections":8},{"connections":5},{"connections":18}];

var connectionCountArray = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < connectionsArray.length; i++) {
    connectionCountArray.push(connectionsArray[i].connections);
}
```

Or you can also get the result by following.

```
var connectionsArray = [{"connections":8},{"connections":5},{"connections":18}];

var connectionCountArray  = connectionsArray.map(function(connection){
    return connection.connections;
});
```

Comment: Or the OP could use jQuery (as he is using it, I suppose), to work direclty with key-value pairs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @lesssugar - I agree, that can also be alternate way of achieving results.

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton! I'm creating charts using Laravel 4, Ajax and jQuery. So Laravel return an array, I got this array with Ajax, then I pass this value to jQuery for create the chart. Thanks again.

Comment: @WillfransVarónSáenz - Good to hear that :)

Comment: Hi guys, I have addressed this issue again and now I got this doubt: `$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",           
    dataType: "html",               
    success: function(data){           
        //var connectionsArray = data; 
        var connectionsArray = [{"connections":8},{"connections":5},{"connections":18}];
        console.log(data);
        var connectionCountArray = [];
        for (var i = 0 ; i < connectionsArray.length; i++) {
            connectionCountArray.push(connectionsArray[i].connections);
        }
   }
});` This working fine.

Comment: When I pass data var doesn't work. var data have this value= `[{"connections":"80"},{"connections":"50"},{"connections":"180"}]` Help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
var obj = $.parseJSON('[{"connections":8},{"connections":5},{"connections":18}]');